# how to turn the flash on the phone (flashlight)?

Tags: android, flashlight

There is a code that is to turn on the flash when you press the button, this is why it is not happening. Help me understand why this is not happening, please. Tested the application on samsung galaxy nexus and lg p970.

Activity:

```
package com.example.Flashlight;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera; 
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Camera camera;
    boolean isFlashOn;
    boolean hasFlash;
    Parameters params;
    Button flashlightButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        checkFlashlight();  
        getCamera(); 
        initFlashlightButton();
    }

    void checkFlashlight() {
        hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        if (!hasFlash) {
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this).create(); alert.setTitle("Error"); 
            alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!"); 
            alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                    finish();
                }
            }); 
        alert.show();
        return;
        } 
    }

    // initialization button and click listener
    private void initFlashlightButton() {
        flashlightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.flash_light);
        flashlightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isFlashOn) turnOffFlash(); 
                else turnOnFlash();
            } 
        }); 
    }

    private void getCamera() {
        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    // here must be of the flash (it is not clear why this is not happening)
    private void turnOnFlash() {
        if (!isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) return;

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
            isFlashOn = true;
        } 
    }

    // flash OFF
    private void turnOffFlash() {
        if (isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) return;

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.stopPreview();
            isFlashOn = false;
        }
    }
```

Layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:layout_height="match_parent"  android:layout_width="match_parent">

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/flash_light"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:text="Flashlight"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.Flashlight"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0">

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

 <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black">

 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
 </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors when you try to use the flashlight?

Comment: No, I do not have errors

Comment: having a search on S.O. revealed that the camera is implemented differently on most devices. I'd advise you look at the links on the right-side of this page for similar issues other people have had.

Comment: I implemented this flashlight app which is so far working for number of devices - you can take a look at my source code: https://bitbucket.org/hqureshi/yafa

Answer (score 0):

To turn on the Camera :

```
    camera = Camera.open();
    Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    camera.setParameters(p);
    camera.startPreview();
```

To turn off the Camera :

```
camera = Camera.open();
Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
camera.setParameters(p);
camera.stopPreview();
```

Also you'll need to put that in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: @ataulm I saw it but this code is enough so why do more when you can do less ?? :)

Comment: In addition it will be easier to get it working with only one button using a boolean.

Comment: Try to open the camera in the if statement instead of using the getCamera();

Comment: fwiw, I tried this code in a blank Android project, tested on my Galaxy Nexus, and it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```